# Wait for main queue being dispatched before continue unit test

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have this method in a class :

```
func handleResp(_ dataGotten: Result<Response?, Error>) {
      ....

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
              ....
                  GlobalStaticStruct.code = 7
              ...
            }
        }
    }
```

And then in my unit testing I have this code :

```
func testhandleResp() {

        subject = SomeClass()
        subject.handleResp(successResponse)
        XCTAssertNotNil(GlobalStaticStruct.code)
    }
```

I need to be able to test that **GlobalStaticStruct.code** is not nil but with the code as it is the test completes before the main queue so the field is nil all the time.

I understand the use of expectations to overcome similar issues but in this case there is no handler I can hook up to.

How can I make my test to wait for the main method to get triggered and finished and THEN test the value of **GlobalStaticStruct.code**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for `main` queue, you can use the fact that it's a serial queue. So if you schedule your check to run on the same queue after `handleResp`, your check will pass. And you can use expectation to synch the test after that check:

```
func testhandleResp() {

    subject = SomeClass()
    subject.handleResp(successResponse) 
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation()
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // scheduled after subject.handleResp
        XCTAssertNotNil(GlobalStaticStruct.code)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
}
```

If it was any other (possibly concurrent) queue, you could do the same, but schedule verification block to run later, using `schedule(after:...`